# Помогите доработать функцию разделения списка

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
def list_slice(lst, count):
    n = len(lst) // count
    grps = (lst[i:i + n] for i in range(0, len(lst), n))
    return list(grps)

list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

При вызове функции `list_slice(list1, 2)` выводит список `[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]`, но мне нужно это `[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6]]`. То есть чтобы длина каждого списка в выведенном списке была 4 элемента.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы слайс по списку берете не так, как нужно. Как вариант Ваш пример можно сделать таким образом:

```
def list_slice(lst, count):
    gen = (lst[count*i:count*(i+1)] for i in range(len(lst) // count + 1))
    return list(filter(bool, gen))

list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print(list_slice(list1, 3))  # [[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

В конце использую `filter(bool, func)` для отсечения пустых списков

Comment: Спасибо вам большое, это то, что мне нужно